# UI Correct on Rendering, does not Appear for Device

Tags: android, user-interface, xamarin, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I am working on an App "Namaz Pro" using Xamarin.Android !

My Problem is that my App shows me my expected UI correctly upon rendering it to
Device : Nexus 4  inside Visual Studio.

I even tried Android Studio and it renders the UI as I want it :

[image: Render]

However My Emulator A Nexus 4 on KitKat is unable to display the same :

[image: Emulator Display]

**UPDATE** : My drawable folder

[image: Drawable Folder]

My Code for Design :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="#efeff4"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="#0c3b07"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDateToday"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Thu 05-May-2016"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:text="28 Rajab 1437"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="30">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/demoImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/fajrImage" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPrayerNow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="Fajr"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPrayerTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="05:30 PM"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:text="Kolkata,India"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It seems like the images are not being copied to the emulator if you change the white text that contains "Fajr" to black is that visible? And which configuration do the images have?

Comment: @Sanne No nothing below the first two lines are visible

Comment: @RahulJha can try to change your image and validate that another small size image is working or not ? I think size might causes an issue.

Comment: @RIYAZ no still wont work

Comment: @RahulJha can you show us your drawable folders with images? top drawable folders must have all images.

Comment: Your layout seems fine. Try to check in real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My drawable folder had hyphens and dashes in filenames. Somehow my project was getting built even after this.
Follow Naming conventions for Xamarin.Android